# how to get root access by giving command and password together on mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I know to get super user access "su" command is provided.After executing this command we need to enter password.Is there a way to do it in a single shot like "some command then password".(i.e. executing command along with password).

Comment: How would that help, since you never, ever have the user's root password?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in root mode by changing the target scheme.

[image]